# php/mysql: table not found on mobile

Tags: php, android, mysql, mobile, xampp

i'm running a local xampp and access it with my mobile (samsung galaxy s4) through wifi.
everything worked nice so far, i'm able to load my web and accessing the database.
then i added a new table to my database, which works on my desktop but when trying to query it from the mobile i'm getting an error `"table mytable.foo doesn't exist"` which is really weird.

i ran this query: `show tables from mytable` which lists all tables, and in fact, the new table doesn't show up on my mobile (both browsers, opera mobile + and the internal one).

i already tried renaming the table, restarting the mobile browser, restarting xammp (+ apache/mysql) without success.

any ideas what could be the reason?

Comment: you have to delete your database from your app on your smartphone

Comment: how do u mean? caching? my database is on my desktop running from xampp ..

Answer (score 0):

U cannot access localhost through your phone by using wifi ... for that u need to host a domain and then try accessing the database on web.. if u want to check whether your database is linked  to localhost use emulator and not your phone..emulator loads data from localhost/phpmyadmin but not your phone.. I hope this helps

Comment: well yes i can access localhost. i added a vhost to xampp using my phone's IP address. i'm able to load my web and such ..

Comment: if your vhost has been correctly setup then u might be have a wrong reference to localhost in your php or android code ... could u please share ur code and logcat..